# Don't draw arrow with \Loop command

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tkz-berge

I'm using `tkz-berge` with latex:

```
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\tikzset{LabelStyle/.style= {fill=white}}
```

And have this graph-drawing code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \SetVertexMath
    \Vertex[x=0,   y=2, L=v_1 ]{v1}
    \Vertex[x=3.5, y=2, L=v_3 ]{v3}
    \Vertex[x=6,   y=2, L=v_5 ]{v5}
    \Vertex[x=1.5, y=0, L=v_2 ]{v2}
    \Vertex[x=4.5, y=0, L=v_4 ]{v4}

    \Edges[                   label={$e_1$}](v1, v2)
    \Edges[style={bend left} ,label={$e_2$}](v2, v3)
    \Edges[style={bend right},label={$e_3$}](v2, v3)
    \Edges[                   label={$e_4$}](v2, v4)
    \Edges[                   label={$e_5$}](v3, v4)
    \Loop[dir=EA, dist=1cm, label={$e_6$}](v4)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem here is, that the `\Loop` command draws the edge differently than the `\Edge` command, namely with an arrow. LaTeX output:

[image]

What do I need to do to remove the arrow and get the exact same style as for normal loops?

Comment: Can you complete your code to a MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that . So everyone can easily test/compile it. With `\documentclass` ... `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is in the documentation for `tkz-graph`: use `style={thick,-}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\tikzset{LabelStyle/.style= {fill=white}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \SetVertexMath
    \Vertex[x=0,   y=2, L=v_1 ]{v1}
    \Vertex[x=3.5, y=2, L=v_3 ]{v3}
    \Vertex[x=6,   y=2, L=v_5 ]{v5}
    \Vertex[x=1.5, y=0, L=v_2 ]{v2}
    \Vertex[x=4.5, y=0, L=v_4 ]{v4}

    \Edges[                   label={$e_1$}](v1, v2)
    \Edges[style={bend left} ,label={$e_2$}](v2, v3)
    \Edges[style={bend right},label={$e_3$}](v2, v3)
    \Edges[                   label={$e_4$}](v2, v4)
    \Edges[                   label={$e_5$}](v3, v4)
    \Loop[dir=EA, dist=1cm, label={$e_6$},style={thick,-}](v4)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]